# Optimizing an update command that aggregates over the entire table for every row

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `company` and `investment`, and I need to have a column in the company table containing the number of investment each company has.

This a sqlite database, by the way.

I tried the following query:

```
UPDATE company SET numlinks = (SELECT count(*) 
                                   FROM investment 
                                   WHERE investment.company_name = company.name);
```

I'm pretty sure the query is right. If I run it for a single company the row is updated correctly. But given that I have over 300K rows, the query starts running and it seems to taking a while.

When running it for a single company with the `.timer ON` command, the CPU used is about 0.03 (I'm not sure the units, I guess its in seconds)

Any ideas on how I could make this faster?

Comment: Do you need a *pure* SQL solution? Or are you using a "front-end" programming language?

Comment: This is not actually for a web application, but I could use something in Python. Why would that be more efficient?

Comment: I think that the SQLite limitations (e.g. you can't use `join` in an `update` sentence) can make it complicated... you will need to enter every single `company` id in your `where` conditions (both in your subquery and in your `update` sentence)... For convenience, I would do it with a front-end solution, rather than directly in SQLite... but that's just me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest solution.

```
alter table company
drop column numlinks
```

One of the first principles of database normalization is to not store calculated values.  When you want to display the number of links, query it when you need it.

```
select company.name, other_stuff, count(*) links
from company join investment on company.name = investment.company_name
group by company.name, other_stuff
```

As an aside, with your current design, you are in trouble if two companies have the same name.  That's why name fields are rarely used to identify a record.

If have trouble understanding this answer, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Given that I will use that computation quite often, I decided it would be useful to store it. Thanks for helping me stick to the good practices.

Answer (score 1):

What you would like to do is to calculate the summaries and then join them into the update statement.  Unfortunately, SQLite does not support joins ([here](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html)), except through such correlated subquery syntax.

One way to make this faster is to create a temporary table with:

```
select company_name, count(*) as cnt
from investment
group by company_name
```

And then do the same thing with this table:

```
set numlinks = (select cnt from TemporaryTable)
```

The performance advantage is twofold.  First you don't have to re-do the calculation for each row.  More importantly, you can create an index on `company_name`, significantly speeding up the query.